# how to reduce size of rt5370sta.ko?

Tags: embedded

I am trying to build rt5370 driver for my embedded board.
I downloaded "DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022.tar.bz2".
First, I exeuted a make without any modification. So, the size of rt5370sta.ko is 942,330 bytes.

And I added my configurations arm-none-linux-gnueabi-, kernel directory.

In ./Makefile

***PLATFORM = ARMV7
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),ARMV7) 
LINUX_SRC = /home/gykim/working/s1cam/bsp/linux/kernel
CROSS_COMPILE = /opt/armv7/codesourcery/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
endif***

In ./os/linux/config.mk

***ifeq ($(PLATFORM),ARMV7)
    EXTRA_CFLAGS := $(WFLAGS) -Wall -I$(RT28xx_DIR)/include
endif***

After make command, the size of rt5370sta.ko is 13,750,585.
The file size is too big.
How can I reduce the size?

Thanks all.

Comment: Perhaps `strip --strip-debug rt5370sta.ko` ?  See also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.linux.development.system/bjU7AfeZl5I

Comment: Thank you. I added "--debug=0" at the WFLAGS.         WFLAGS := -DAGGREGATION_SUPPORT -DPIGGYBACK_SUPPORT -DWMM_SUPPORT  -DLINUX -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs --debug=0

Comment: The name would suggest that WFLAGS is intended for warning flags. There may be a more appropriate place for that.

Comment: Thansk for great advice. I added at the EXTRA_CFLAGS. So, EXTRA_CFLAGS := $(WFLAGS) --debug=0 -I$(RT28xx_DIR)/include

Comment: Also I would expect the build system to have separate debug and release targets - building for release may apply optimisation that is not otherwise performed by simply discarding the debug symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that your build includes debug symbols.  Either explicitly build for release by whatever means is documented for the build system or strip the symbols after with:

```
strip --strip-debug rt5370sta.ko
```

Note however that it is likely that a debug build is also not optimised, and the resulting build may be larger and/or slower than you might be able to achieve, so it is probably better to use the build-system's release configuration.

Comment: I guess I need the strip command for arm. I tried to execute "strip -d rt5370sta.ko". But I met Unable to recognise the format of the input file `os/linux/rt5370sta.ko'. So, temporarily, I seemed that need the "--debug=0".

Comment: You must have an appropriate version of `strip` - it is part of binutils in the GNU toolchain.  Probably called `arm-linux-gnueabi-strip`.  Often in cross development an environment is set-up so that the default names map to the cross-tools - not in your case I guess.  To automate this in the build, I think the `INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1` may be what you need - somewhere - I am no expert, just good at Google!